# Satellite Images for the Mediterranean Sea Oil Spill

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, data, environmental-monitoring

I am looking to obtain free satellite images to detect oil spills in the Mediterranean sea. What sensors would be most appropriate for this task and where can I download this type of data?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Landsat](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/landsat/main/index.html) or [MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/) for this task.  You can access Landsat or MODIS data through [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or [Reverb|Echo](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=%E2%9C%93&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle).  There are a number of publications on the subject to help you along the way:

- [Brekke, C., & Solberg, A. H. (2005). Oil spill detection by
  satellite remote sensing. Remote sensing of environment, 95(1),
  1-13.](http://optics.marine.usf.edu/~hu/scratch/gower/pdf/Oil_spill_review_RSE2005.pdf)
- [Hu, C., Li, X., Pichel, W. G., & Muller‐Karger, F. E. (2009).
  Detection of natural oil slicks in the NW Gulf of Mexico using MODIS
  imagery. Geophysical Research Letters, 36(1).](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2008GL036119/full)

Comment: With that resolution, you wont be able to see a lot in MODIS and furthermore for analysis i'd recommend LS.

Comment: @g07kore MODIS has much higher spectral resolution than Landsat and, therefore, is very useful for detecting large scale phenomenon such as oil slicks.  The second paper shows that the researches successfully used MODIS to detect oil slicks even 75m in width.

Comment: I am aware of that and did not believe it before i saw your second link. I was more concerned that with the spatial resolution of 250m you'll lose a lot of information. Especially the second figure comparing MODIS and SAR imagery is impressive.